# Microcontroller with rotary encoder and bluetooth capabilities

Tags: wireless, components, bluetooth, microprocessor

I am looking for advice on (what to use/how to make) a rotary encoder that I can connect to through bluetooth. I am writing an app that needs to display on screen in real time to the user the number of rotations as they are turning it. Also, I need to have the micro-controller record the revolutions per day so I can keep track of revolutions if their computer is asleep.

Criteria:

1. Must be stand alone
2. Has to be bluetooth compatible with a pc, mac, android and iphone.
3. Has to be able to store up to 7 days of data (this would be a very small amount of data, just the number of rotations per day and the timestamp).
4. Has to be small and cheep.

I was thinking a microcontroller with just a rotary encoder and bluetooth capabilities.

I have seen microcontroller like the Arduino and think they would be good to start with but I was looking for something that could actually be used in a final product.

Comment: Use a bluetooth module like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10559 It appears as a regular serial port to the PC and as a regular UART to the microcontroller. Then all you need is a microcontroller that can decode a rotary encoder (2 digital inputs) and communicate using UART (an extra two pins) and a couple bytes EEPROM to store revolutions.

Comment: What is the difference between an Arduino and a "something that could actually be used in a final product"?

Comment: The impression I get is a Arduino is a learning tool, not something you would see in a real product that you would buy, like a Fitbit.

Comment: I see that the WRL-10559 you mentioned, is Bluetooth v2.0 compatible. Do you know what version of Bluetooth it uses? Thanks

Comment: Nope, it is just a random hit on a random search engine. Search for 'bluetooth module breakout' and you find several modules at varying prices.

Comment: There are very small Arduino's and even smaller clones. Also once developed on Arduino software is easily ported to a stand alone ATtiny or ATmega. The advantage clearly being not having to design the hardware/PCB/soldering/... until you have a working product.

Answer (score 2):

Any small micro plus a cheap BT module should be suitable for this.

For example, a [PIC 12 or 16F](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/8bit/), with something [like this BT Module](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5V-JY-MCU-HC-06-V1-04-Bluetooth-Transeiver-RF-Module-Serial-Port-51-AVR-MCU-ARM-/261121350024?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3ccc0b9988) (I have used a [surface mount version](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Wireless-Serial-Bluetooth-Transceiver-RF-Module-rs232-/120939375441?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item1c288c6b51) of one of these successfully in a recent prototype) plus the encoder could be thrown together very quickly for proof of concept purposes. On the PC side, Java would be best so you can port to Android, Mac, Linux, etc.

Comment: Does it matter what language the microcontroller is programmed with? I was going to write the program that reads the data in c# for windows, Objective C for mac and java for Android. Thanks

Comment: I'd go for a portable language like C++. Unsure about pros/cons for Java. The advantage of using a portable language (like C++) is that you only have to write (and maintain) a single source tree. All platforms support C++ (Win, Mac, Linux, AVR, PIC, ...)

Comment: Are you talking about using C++ for the microcontroller? Thanks

Comment: Sorry if thats a stupid question, but I have never programed a microcontroller. Thanks

Comment: C is the language if choice for small micros (or assembler) Some of the larger micros have C++ compilers available, but not something like the PIC12/16/18 mentioned above. @jippie was talking about C++ for your PC side stuff.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know the difference between C and C++. I know C# for microcontrollers is most of the time out of the question *and* I know I use some C++ things for Arduino. Whether Arduino does full C++, I don't know. Also source files for my ATtiny's have a `.cpp` extension and for these too I am aware I use some C++ specifics, but honestly I wouldn't know the formal difference between the two. C++ for PC/Linux/Mac is definitely OK as far as I'm concerned, as it is highly portable (and I don't mind compiling stuff).

Comment: The pros of Java are that it's very easily portable - it certainly covers 3 of the 4 platforms above (not sure about iPhone as I have never developed anything for it) C++ is a similar choice too, but the Android platform is based around Java (interestingly, the underlying native Android stuff is C++ I believe, but that is more for the "hardcore" Android programmer)

Answer (score 1):

TI sells a complete bluetooth + microcontroller solution (CC256x + MSP430 or Stellaris). Check out their [evaluation platforms](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC256x_EVM_Platform). The EZ430 solution is very nice and should work for you since it's compact and you can connect a rotary encoder.

Comment: If I was to write a demo program on the Arduino, do you know if I would be able to port it onto the CC256x + MSP430 or Stellaris? Thanks

Comment: In a way yes. Both are programmed using C, but the CC256x+MSP430 has a certain way of doing things to be able to send the data. Arduino code is not directly translatable to MSP430/Stellaris code.

Answer (score 0):

The primary feature you should probably be looking for in the microcontoller is high speed inputs. Your encoder will be completely useless if your microcontroller can't keep up and it will all look like noise (assuming you're using a quadrature encoder). You should also do some research on noise filtering encoders for the same reason.

That being said, if you're looking at creating a prototype, (without having checked on the speed of the inputs) go with the Arduino because most of the work is already done for you and just get a Bluetooth shield. You can always look into making your own Arduinos (they are open source after all) and you can get the price around $3 a board.

If you don't go the Arduino route, it's a matter of specking out a Bluetooth module and looking at what interfacing options are available.

[Edit] It sounds from the comments like I'm used to using higher resolution encoders than many general applications require, so I may have overstated the necessity of high speed inputs. Either way, you should at least ask the question about what kind of resolution you need and whether your inputs will lose pulses.

Comment: You would have difficulty finding a micro-controller which did not have fast enough inputs.  However, one with at least two bi-directional edge interrupts (ideally where both edges can be enabled at the same time) will make software simpler, though is not required.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Shouldn't that depend on the resolution of the encoder? I come from the PLC side of the tracks and we typically use very high resolution encoders such that you have to actually make sure that you're using the designated high speed inputs or you will lose counts. It's also sensitive to scan time if you're not using interrupts or parallel processing to find transitions between scans.

Comment: The inputs on a processor are typically a lot faster than those you might find on a packaged module, especially if it has multiplexing or generic filtering.  Or do you commonly work with encoders having MHz output rates?

Comment: you don't really need high speed inputs; anything with either timer event counters or interrupt-on-change pins would work (with the better solution being the former). If he's counting incredibly high rate rotations he may need a better micro but pretty much anything should be able to handle this part of the design.

Comment: I am used to MHz encoders, mainly in industrial servo motion applications. It's common to have millions of pulse per revolution.

Comment: I just need it to count every rotation and the time between rotations. It will be hand turned so speed should not be an issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what is the rate of rotation? How many rotations per day are you designing for?

You may be able to get away with just the bluetooth chip and writing for its microcontroller to watch your encoder. The (old) BC4 has options where you can write you code for a "virtual" chip running inside it. That would get you down to a single chip to do everything.

The traditional way of doing this is to use any of the readily-available bluetooth modules that expose themselves as bluetooth serial ports, and then use a small micro to talk to their "real" serial ports. Others have already answered with example modules. Make sure you use a module that your micro can just talk to, otherwise you may have to implement a lower level protocol such as H4, BCSP or somesuch in order to use it. (and if you go that route, try Matthias Ringwald's excellent [btstack](http://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/GettingStarted); I have successfully pared this down to fit in an LPC2100 and talk to mobile phones.